# HTML form to CSV and insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, csv

I currently have a site that uploads a CSV and displays it in a preview table as a form that can be edited (if any CSV values are wrong).

[image]

It works great, but I need to insert this into a database table with any edits that are made within the form. I have an array that puts the uploaded CSV into this form, but now I think I need to create a new CSV from this form and submit THAT CSV into the database. I've seen some tutorials but I'm unclear on how to do it from this table/form.

Here is the code for the existing preview form:

```
 if(isset($_POST['preview']))
{
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;
?><form><?

    echo '<table>';

    /*WE WILL NEED TO QA CONDITIONS AND HIGHLIGHT IN RED HERE. ALSO NEED BORDER STYLINGS*/

    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }

    echo '<tbody>';

    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';

}
?></form>
```

Since this doesn't have values for each field in the form, I'm unsure of the best way to create a CSV from this and insert it into my staging table.

UPDATE - the below code is my first attempt at using my CSV upload array

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {

            $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");

            while (($filesop = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

            $coldata = array();

            $coldata["orderNumber"] = $filesop[0];
            $coldata["workOrderPacket"] = $filesop[1];
            $coldata["workOrderNum"] = $filesop[2];
            $coldata["lowSideMIUNumArriv"] = $filesop[3];
            $coldata["lowSideMIUNumDepart"] = $filesop[4];
            $coldata["highSideMIUNumArriv"] = $filesop[5];
            $coldata["highSideMIUNumDepart"] = $filesop[6];
            $coldata["accountNum"] = $filesop[7];
            $coldata["filler1"] = $filesop[8];
            $coldata["address"] = $filesop[9];
            $coldata["filler2"] = $filesop[10];
            $coldata["date"] = $filesop[11];
            $coldata["utility"] = $filesop[12];
            $coldata["serialNumber"] = $filesop[13];
            $coldata["serviceName"] = $filesop[14];
            $coldata["locationNotes"] = $filesop[15];
            $coldata["locationComments"] = $filesop[16];
            $coldata["filler3"] = $filesop[17];
            $coldata["WaterValveArriv"] = $filesop[18];
            $coldata["WaterValveDepart"] = $filesop[19];
            $coldata["meterSize"] = $filesop[20];
            $coldata["meterType"] = $filesop[21];
            $coldata["manufacturer"] = $filesop[22];
            $coldata["registration"] = $filesop[23];
            $coldata["technician"] = $filesop[24];
            $coldata["linePressurePSI"] = $filesop[25];
            $coldata["filler4"] = $filesop[26];
            $coldata["filler5"] = $filesop[27];
            $coldata["lowSideRrBefore"] = $filesop[28];
            $coldata["highSideRrBefore"] = $filesop[29];
            $coldata["lowSideRrAfter"] = $filesop[30];
            $coldata["highSideRrAfter"] = $filesop[31];
            $coldata["vgOxygen"] = $filesop[32];
            $coldata["vgCombustGas"] = $filesop[33];
            $coldata["vgCarbonMon"] = $filesop[34];
            $coldata["vgHydroSulf"] = $filesop[35];
            $coldata["test1TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[36];
            $coldata["test1MeterVol"] = $filesop[37];
            $coldata["test1TesterVol"] = $filesop[38];
            $coldata["test1Accuracy"] = $filesop[39];
            $coldata["test1CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[40];
            $coldata["test2TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[41];
            $coldata["test2MeterVol"] = $filesop[42];
            $coldata["test2TesterVol"] = $filesop[43];
            $coldata["test2Accuracy"] = $filesop[44];
            $coldata["test2CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[45];
            $coldata["test3TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[46];
            $coldata["test3MeterVol"] = $filesop[47];
            $coldata["test3TesterVol"] = $filesop[48];
            $coldata["test3Accuracy"] = $filesop[49];
            $coldata["test3CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[50];
            $coldata["test4TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[51];
            $coldata["test4MeterVol"] = $filesop[52];
            $coldata["test4TesterVol"] = $filesop[53];
            $coldata["test4Accuracy"] = $filesop[54];
            $coldata["test4CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[55];
            $coldata["test5TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[56];
            $coldata["test5MeterVol"] = $filesop[57];
            $coldata["test5TesterVol"] = $filesop[58];
            $coldata["test5Accuracy"] = $filesop[59];
            $coldata["test5CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[60];
            $coldata["test6TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[61];
            $coldata["test6MeterVol"] = $filesop[62];
            $coldata["test6TesterVol"] = $filesop[63];
            $coldata["test6Accuracy"] = $filesop[64];
            $coldata["test6CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[65];
            $coldata["test7TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[66];
            $coldata["test7MeterVol"] = $filesop[67];
            $coldata["test7TesterVol"] = $filesop[68];
            $coldata["test7Accuracy"] = $filesop[69];
            $coldata["test7CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[70];
            $coldata["test8TestRateGPM"] = $filesop[71];
            $coldata["test8MeterVol"] = $filesop[72];
            $coldata["test8TesterVol"] = $filesop[73];
            $coldata["test8Accuracy"] = $filesop[74];
            $coldata["test8CorrectAcc"] = $filesop[75];
            $coldata["inletValveLoc"] = $filesop[76];
            $coldata["inletValveSize"] = $filesop[77];
            $coldata["InletValveType"] = $filesop[78];
            $coldata["inletValveCond"] = $filesop[79];
            $coldata["outletValveLoc"] = $filesop[80];
            $coldata["outletValveSize"] = $filesop[81];
            $coldata["outletValveType"] = $filesop[82];
            $coldata["outletValveCond"] = $filesop[83];
            $coldata["bypassValveLoc"] = $filesop[84];
            $coldata["bypassValveSize"] = $filesop[85];
            $coldata["bypassValveType"] = $filesop[86];
            $coldata["bypassValveCond"] = $filesop[87];
            $coldata["vaultLength"] = $filesop[88];
            $coldata["vaultWidth"] = $filesop[89];
            $coldata["vaultHeight"] = $filesop[90];
            $coldata["meterLocation"] = $filesop[91];
            $coldata["testPort"] = $filesop[92];
            $coldata["testPortInstalled"] = $filesop[93];
            $coldata["testPortSize"] = $filesop[94];
            $coldata["picture"] = $filesop[95];
            $coldata["timeTested"] = $filesop[96];
            $coldata["comments"] = $filesop[97];
            $coldata["testResults"] = $filesop[98];
            $coldata["retest"] = $filesop[99];
            $coldata["test1TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[100];
            $coldata["test1MeterVol2"] = $filesop[101];
            $coldata["test1TesterVol2"] = $filesop[102];
            $coldata["test1Accuracy2"] = $filesop[103];
            $coldata["test1CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[104];
            $coldata["test2TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[105];
            $coldata["test2MeterVol2"] = $filesop[106];
            $coldata["test2TesterVol2"] = $filesop[107];
            $coldata["test2Accuracy2"] = $filesop[108];
            $coldata["test2CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[109];
            $coldata["test3TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[110];
            $coldata["test3MeterVol2"] = $filesop[111];
            $coldata["test3TesterVol2"] = $filesop[112];
            $coldata["test3Accuracy2"] = $filesop[113];
            $coldata["test3CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[114];
            $coldata["test4TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[115];
            $coldata["test4MeterVol2"] = $filesop[116];
            $coldata["test4TesterVol2"] = $filesop[117];
            $coldata["test4Accuracy2"] = $filesop[118];
            $coldata["test4CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[119];
            $coldata["test5TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[120];
            $coldata["test5MeterVol2"] = $filesop[121];
            $coldata["test5TesterVol2"] = $filesop[122];
            $coldata["test5Accuracy2"] = $filesop[123];
            $coldata["test5CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[124];
            $coldata["test6TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[125];
            $coldata["test6MeterVol2"] = $filesop[126];
            $coldata["test6TesterVol2"] = $filesop[127];
            $coldata["test6Accuracy2"] = $filesop[128];
            $coldata["test6CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[129];
            $coldata["test7TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[130];
            $coldata["test7MeterVol2"] = $filesop[131];
            $coldata["test7TesterVol2"] = $filesop[132];
            $coldata["test7Accuracy2"] = $filesop[133];
            $coldata["test7CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[134];
            $coldata["test8TestRateGPM2"] = $filesop[135];
            $coldata["test8MeterVol2"] = $filesop[136];
            $coldata["test8TesterVol2"] = $filesop[137];
            $coldata["test8Accuracy2"] = $filesop[138];
            $coldata["test8CorrectAcc2"] = $filesop[139];
            $coldata["filler6"] = $filesop[140];
            $coldata["filler7"] = $filesop[141];
            $coldata["filler8"] = $filesop[142];
            $coldata["filler9"] = $filesop[143];
            $coldata["filler10"] = $filesop[144];
            $coldata["filler11"] = $filesop[145];
            $coldata["filler12"] = $filesop[146];
            $coldata["serviceAddCorrect"] = $filesop[147];
            $coldata["serviceLoccCorrect"] = $filesop[148];
            $coldata["meterNumberCorrect"] = $filesop[149];
            $coldata["lowRegisterCorrect"] = $filesop[150];
            $coldata["lowRegisterType"] = $filesop[151];
            $coldata["lowRegisterSize"] = $filesop[152];
            $coldata["highRegisterCorrect"] = $filesop[153];
            $coldata["highRegisterSize"] = $filesop[154];
            $coldata["highRegisterType"] = $filesop[155];
            $coldata["meterLidType"] = $filesop[156];
            $coldata["meterLidMaterial"] = $filesop[157];
            $coldata["lidFit"] = $filesop[158];
            $coldata["lidCondition"] = $filesop[159];
            $coldata["antennaeMountCor"] = $filesop[160];
            $coldata["antennaePosition"] = $filesop[161];
            $coldata["registerCondition"] = $filesop[162];
            $coldata["MIUwire"] = $filesop[163];
            $coldata["registerPinArriv"] = $filesop[164];
            $coldata["registerPinDepart"] = $filesop[165];
            $coldata["vaultType"] = $filesop[166];
            $coldata["vaultSafe"] = $filesop[167];
            $coldata["vaultLadder"] = $filesop[168];
            $coldata["workOrderType"] = $filesop[169];
            $coldata["workOrderLocation"] = $filesop[170];
            $coldata["completeMeter"] = $filesop[171];
            $coldata["ume"] = $filesop[172];
            $coldata["discChamber"] = $filesop[173];
            $coldata["turbineChamber"] = $filesop[174];
            $coldata["automaticValve"] = $filesop[175];
            $coldata["strainer"] = $filesop[176];
            $coldata["lowRegister"] = $filesop[177];
            $coldata["highRegister"] = $filesop[178];
            $coldata["miu"] = $filesop[179];
            $coldata["antennae"] = $filesop[180];
            $coldata["calibrationVane"] = $filesop[181];
            $coldata["meterLeakRepaired"] = $filesop[182];
            $coldata["workOrderType2"] = $filesop[183];
            $coldata["strainerPresent"] = $filesop[184];
            $coldata["apparentLeak"] = $filesop[185];
            $coldata["leakLocation"] = $filesop[186];
            $coldata["leakType"] = $filesop[187];
            $coldata["locateBypassValve"] = $filesop[188];
            $coldata["locateInletValve"] = $filesop[189];
            $coldata["locateOutletValve"] = $filesop[190];
            $coldata["PreformShutdown"] = $filesop[191];
            $coldata["turnOnWater"] = $filesop[192];
            $coldata["repairLid"] = $filesop[193];
            $coldata["repairVault"] = $filesop[194];
            $coldata["repairLadder"] = $filesop[195];
            $coldata["repairLeak"] = $filesop[196];
            $coldata["repairBypassValve"] = $filesop[197];
            $coldata["repairInletValve"] = $filesop[198];
            $coldata["repairOutletValve"] = $filesop[199];
            $coldata["latitude"] = $filesop[200];
            $coldata["longitude"] = $filesop[201];
            $coldata["onsiteSurveyTestCost"] = $filesop[202];
            $coldata["onsiteSurveyTestRepairCost"] = $filesop[203];
            $coldata["offsiteSurveyTestCost"] = $filesop[204];
            $coldata["offsiteSurveyTestRepairCost"] = $filesop[205];
            $coldata["onsiteTestOnlyCost"] = $filesop[206];
            $coldata["onsiteTestRepairOnlyCost"] = $filesop[207];
            $coldata["onsiteRepairOnly"] = $filesop[208];
            $coldata["testPort2"] = $filesop[209];
            $coldata["repairCompleteMeterReplacement"] = $filesop[210];
            $coldata["repairCompleteMeterReplacementLaborCost"] = $filesop[211];
            $coldata["umeCost"] = $filesop[212];
            $coldata["umeLaborCost"] = $filesop[213];
            $coldata["rotatingLowSideDiskChamber"] = $filesop[214];
            $coldata["rotatingLowSideDiskChamberLaborCost"] = $filesop[215];
            $coldata["turbineChamberCost"] = $filesop[216];
            $coldata["turbineChamberLaborCost"] = $filesop[217];
            $coldata["automaticValveCost"] = $filesop[218];
            $coldata["automaticValveLaborCost"] = $filesop[219];
            $coldata["strainerCost"] = $filesop[220];
            $coldata["strainerLaborCost"] = $filesop[221];
            $coldata["lowRegisterCost"] = $filesop[222];
            $coldata["lowRegisterLaborCost"] = $filesop[223];
            $coldata["highRegisterCost"] = $filesop[224];
            $coldata["highRegisterLaborCost"] = $filesop[225];
            $coldata["miuCost"] = $filesop[226];
            $coldata["miuLaborCost"] = $filesop[227];
            $coldata["totalCost"] = $filesop[228];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - CSV upload from new preview window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722270/php-csv-upload-from-new-preview-window)

Comment: This is the 3rd time you are asking the same question within a couple of hours.

Comment: But if the CSV is in a particular order (it's uploaded daily with the same 235 fields) and needs to be inserted in that order into my 235 field staging table, wouldn't I need to keep that order by saving this as a new CSV? Since the code above is all I have for the form, and it just puts the entire CSV into one table, would I be able to insert it as a form for all 5 or 6 rows without having explicitly named fields?

Comment: @Shadow I realized a few errors I had and deleted the previous question to repost with a different approach.

Comment: The above code doesn't contain any form or input fields at all so I'm struggling to see how that code could produce that image.

Comment: I just went through you question history and I was wrong. This is the 5th time you asked the same question. OK, you removed one, now only 4 remains. This is still a duplicate question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry, I realized that it pasted the old code. It now has the form tags that create the form in the image

Comment: Then update the code to the _actual_ code. And it doesn't seem like you have an issue with creating the form so maybe you should show us your attempt to solve your _actual issue_?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the above code is the actual code, it had previously pasted the non-form version, which is why I updated it. I tried to solve it by attaching my original CSV upload script to the submit button, but it doesn't work because the uploaded file isn't recognized. I'm updating now with my CSV upload code.

Comment: You're not making any sense. The above code IS non-form code and since you've asked the same question over and over, you should have gotten enough pointers to actually try something (yes, I checked your other questions). It feels like it doesn't matter what people say, you will just keep posting the same question over and over until someone gives you all the code (which isn't likely to happen).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added the code I tried previously, which is the array that I use to submit the CSV without preview, as well as supplying the preview form with the info. When I attach this (and the SQL insert statement) to the submit button, it just loops through empty entries and I have to kill the process in PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The above has the form tags, it's what I'm using on my site to create the form in the screenshot, therefore it is not non-form code. I also haven't been given any actual pointers except to google how to convert an html table to a CSV but that doesn't work with this code. I'm not asking for someone to give me the code, since I've built this entire site up to this point, I'm just stuck here and I don't know enough PHP to really get it where it needs to be

Comment: Wrapping a table in a `<form>`-tag (which is GET and not POST by default) doesn't make the table a form. Please read some HTML 101.

Comment: I'm aware of the HTML side of creating a form, but wrapping it in a form tag does make the values editable, like in the screenshot. Also, the POST in the code above is corresponding to the upload page which has the preview button, therefore the POST is necessary in retrieving the preview PHP page